# define a variable of struct in assembler x86 32/64 bit

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a problem with struct in assembly.
Now I define a struct in this way

```
$struct date
  giorno db ?
  mese   db ?
  anno   dd ?
ends date

local data1:data$
```

I have 4 questions:

1) If I insert another local directive do I have other variable or do I rename the first variable?

2) When I do `mov eax,date.giorno` does `eax` have a *data* of `data.giorno` or does `eax` have *address* of `data.giorno`?

3) Can I make to insert all struct in the stack with only 1 push statement?

4) If I have 2 variables `data1` and `data2` of same type how I can create a macro?

Thanks in advance those who help me understand.

Comment: I don't see any mention in your question of which assembler you're using.

Comment: *3) Can I make to insert all struct in the stack with only 1 push statement?*  If you have your whole struct packed into a register, then yes.  Otherwise no.  It would have to be a 64-bit register to hold your 4+1+1 byte struct.  In assembly language, everything is just bytes.  Some assemblers may have fancy syntax to help you do what you want, but you have to understand exactly what bytes are going where.  Can't answer the rest of this since I don't use MASM.